# How to close chrome notifications programmaticaly without clearing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am currently using a user supplied variable to set the length of the time a notification popup is displayed to the user. However, I assume because I am using `chome.notifications.clear()`, I have the unwanted side effect of notifications not being stored in the system tray/bell icon menu.

Is there a way where I can progammaticaly set the amount of duration a notification popup is displayed, without removing it from the list of notifications in the system tray/bell icon menu?

Here is a snippet of my notification creation code:

```
var opt = {
  type: "basic",
  title: notification.app + ": " + notification.title,
  message: "",
  iconUrl: dataUri,
  contextMessage: time
}

var note = chrome.notifications.create("someid", opt, function(id){
        console.log("notification id: " + id);
        setTimeout(function(){
                chrome.notifications.clear(id,function(wasCleared){
                        //need to do anything?
                });
        }, get_value_from_local("note_time") * 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a notification property, `priority`, that you can use to emulate the behavior you need.

The [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) on notifications is, frankly, piss-poor, but more information can be extracted from linked articles. [This one](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications) (emphasis mine):

> Notifications can be assigned a priority between -2 to 2. **Priorities < 0 are only shown in the center**; priorities > 0 are shown for increasing duration and more high priority notifications can be displayed in the system tray.

In fact, you can *update* the priority value to show or hide your notification.

```
chrome.notifications.create(
  "test",
  {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "ion.png",
    title: "Test",
    message: "Hide me!"
  },
  function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
      chrome.notifications.update("test", {priority: -1}, function(){});
    }, 1000);
  }
);
```

Likewise if you `update` the priority to 0 or above, an existing notification will show up again.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately the low priority then causes the notification to go to the bottom of the bell icon list, and causes them to apparently disappear when a new one comes in.